# Using knobs addon in Storybook 5.3 beta with HTML elements

Tags: storybook

I'm looking for help, doc or examples of how to implement knobs with storybook/html using the Storybook 5.3 beta version.

For now, my stories are OK, I have the knobs panel but It's telling me it didn't detect any knobs.
By the way, the attribute and text set with knobs are rendered with their default value.
I just can't tweak them in Knobs panel.

Thanks